# KAA 0.8.0 sending multicast notifications over and over upon connection of server (rebooting)

Tags: notifications, multicast, kaa

We have an issue in KAA 0.8.0 that is causing our endpoints to received many multicast notifications over and over.  We can not stop it.  What we did was attempt to send a Factory Reset Notification to one device from the KAA Admin, and did not realize it was sending the Event to ALL devices.  How can we stop these notifications from attempting the factory reset to the devices every time the device reconnects to the server?

Comment: please kindly provide more details:  
  
1/ Do I understand correctly : you have a set of multicats notifications and when device reconnected it receives all those notifications even if they were received before to reconnect?  
  
2/ Do you know about the feature of client and server profiles? you can setup profile filters, then setup groups based on filters, and then your devices will receive only notifications destinated to their group based on profile.
  
3/ Are you able to provide some code snippets to reproduce your particular problem?